# invalid vector <T> subscript

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, complex-numbers, subscript

I am trying to make a two-dimensional vector where the 0 and 1 coordinates are both complex numbers.

Defining the vector seems to be working fine, but when I try to access it, I get an error that pops up in a new tab with a load of gibberish, but somewhere in there it says `invalid vector <T> subscript`.

The (abridged) code is:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    vector<vector<complex<double>>> rho;
    for(int g = 0; g < 4; ++g){
        for(int h = 0; h < 4; ++h){
            rho.push_back(vector<complex<double>>(2));
            rho.at(g).at(h) = 0;
            cout << rho.at(g).at(h)<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an invalid subscript because you have an outer vector holding inner vectors. Your outer vector is adding a new vector on the inner loop so you are pushing back a lot of vectors of size 2, h ranges from 0 to 3 and 2 and 3 are invalid subscripts for all your inner vectors.

It's unfortunately one of those "useless contextless" errors. Would be more useful if it at least said "invalid subscript 2 for vector of size 2"

Answer (score -2):

I think for C++, the angled brackets need to separated by spaces.
The code works as is when I do that. Look at this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int g = 0;
    int h = 0;
    vector<vector<complex<double > > > rho;
    rho.push_back(vector<complex<double > >(2));
    rho.at(g).at(h) = 0;
    cout << rho.at(g).at(h)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You are correct; this deficiency is supposed to be fixed in C++11, but most compilers don't have C++11 enabled by default yet.

Comment: I think something is wrong somewhere else, i've copied your code into a fresh project and it works fine (with or without the spaces). Thanks tho :) xx

Comment: omg, i just realised that i am the BIGGEST idiot, ive set the number of dimensions to 2 and then tried to write to the 4th dimension DUUUH